# IPC between FastCGI C++ / Nginx and C++ Application

Tags: c++, nginx, ipc, fastcgi, fastcgi++

I'm trying to create a Gateway which offers a RESTful interface to send/receive messages to Devices which communicate over Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE). Basically it translates GATT to HTTP and vice versa.

The basic architecture looks as follows:

A BLE Dongle is connected to a Linux computer (f.e. Raspberry Pi) a C-Program opens a serial connection to the BLE Dongle to send/receive/process messages. It receives requests from a C++ Application over IPC using a TCP/IP Socket and also uses this socket to forward replies from BLE Devices (f.e. Sensors) to the C++ Application (which acts as a multithreaded server for each connected BLE Dongle).

The C++ Application saves this information (f.e. discovered devices, connected devices and their data) and also implements an interface to control basic Bluetooth Low Energy functions like Discovery,Connect.. etc.

A client can send HTTP Requests (GET/POST) to a Nginx Webserver which uses FastCGI. I would like to parse the requests in this FastCGI Application and then communicate with the C++ Application to execute the commands

f.e. Client opens an URI xyz/discover sending a GET Request. The FastCGI Application parses this requests and calls the Discover function of the C++ Application to start a Bluetooth Low Energy discovery.

My Question is how to best communicate between the C++ Application and the FastCGI C++ Application.

My Ideas:

- The C++ App forks a new child which does exec fcgi-spawn (path to my fcgi app as an argument). Then create two pipes for full-duplex communication between parent and child
- Using named Pipes between both processes
- Is it a good idea to just integrate the FastCGI functionality in my C++ Application? The C++ App runs several Threads: one to accept new TCP connections in case a new Dongle is connected. It starts a Thread for each new Dongle. Could I just create another thread which is responsible for parsing FastCGI Requests?

Since I never really worked with FastCGI and nginx I'm just learning as I go. So I would be grateful for some input. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is way too broad

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes I'm afraid you're right.... basically I'm looking for input from someone who did something similar to what I'm trying to do. Don't know how to be more specific

Comment: Do you need bidirectional async. communications or just request/response protocol from nginx to your C++ App?

Comment: Ok for future readers: I created something similar to the multithreading c example application. The FCGX_Request is stored on a lockfree work queue (by the fcgi threads) and worker threads process them.  They put the finished http header/body (using the information in the envp struct in FCGX_Request, you can apply FCGX_GetParam) on the socket which is in the FCGX_request (out) and finally Finish the request